# 'Where it feels'

Tags: subjects

I am probably asking a stupid question, but I am not an english speaker.
The sentence 'where it feels like home', is it correct? The subject 'it' after the adverb 'where' is my main doubt.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Feels like", in this context, is an idiom.  Your usage sounds correct, though it's hard to say for sure without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full sentence, but a sentence fragment. If it were a part of a full sentence, it would be called a ***wh*-relative construction.** Examples of full sentences that include that relative are

*I want to stay in a place **where it feels like home.***
*New York is  **where it feels like home.***